# Apache - strange requests in logs

Tags: http, webserver, apache, logging

I'm running webserver on Debian8 64bit (`2.6.32-042stab120.16`) with Apache/2.4.10.
Today in Apache `access.log` I found these entries:

```
164.52.7.132 - - [26/Jun/2017:07:16:23 -0400] "\x16\x03\x01\x01\"\x01" 400 0 "-" "-"
164.52.7.132 - - [26/Jun/2017:07:16:30 -0400] "USER test +iw test :Test Wuz Here" 400 0 "-" "-"
164.52.7.132 - - [26/Jun/2017:07:16:30 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4191 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"l,
```

I'm aware that somebody is trying to test some vulnerabilities on my webserver. I'm concerned especially about first request from this host - what may this be, some function coded in hex or dec?

Should I do some more checks on this server?

Is this a known vulnerability? If yes, can I protect somehow from these kind of attacks?

Comment: I have the same 3 entries in my logs, also from an IP in Hong Kong. The `\"` in the middle of the string is interesting. I wonder if this is testing for a vulnerability.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if these chars \” were something like an escape string for some function..? But I haven’t found more info on it. Nor have I noticed server compromise or data breach. How about you Mat? If you have more info feel free to comment or share as an answer on this topic

Answer (score 13):

> I'm concerned especially about first request from this host - what may this be, some function coded in hex or dec?

What you see in `\x16\x03\x01\x01...` is just the start of a TLS 1.0 handshake, i.e. content type (0x16 = handshake) followed by TLS version (0x0301 = TLS 1.0). Looks like somebody tried to speak HTTPS on port 80 instead of 443.

Comment: Could this be considered as a probe by an adversary checking to see if you have SSL installed?

Comment: @RickHenderson: It could, but it also could be a simple misconfiguration by the client. Or it could be that somebody published a URL as `https://example.com:80` and the client just visited it. There is no actual evidence for an actual attack or probing here.